# Kubernetes nginx-ingress controller always 401 http response

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm researching kubernetes and trying to configure nginx-ingress controller. So I created yaml config file for it, like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: acme.com
      http:
        paths: 
          - path: /api/platforms
            pathType: Prefix
            backend: 
              service:
                name: platforms-clusterip-service
                port: 
                  number: 80
          - path: /api/c/platforms
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: command-clusterip-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

And created relevant services like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: platforms-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: platformservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: platformservice
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: platformservice
          image: yuriyborovskyi91/platformsservice:latest
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: platforms-clusterip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector: 
    app: platformservice
  ports:
  - name: platformservice
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

And added acme.com to windows hosts file, like:

```
127.0.0.1 acme.com
```

But when trying to access http://acme.com/api/platforms or any other api route, I'm receiving 401 http error, and confused by it, because I didn't configure any authorization. Using all default settings. If to call my service by nodeport everything works fine.
Output of my kubectl get services, where service I'm trying to access running:
[image: kubectl get services]

and response of kubectl get services --namespace=ingress-nginx
[image: kubectl get services --namespace]

Comment: Are you sure you are pointing to the correct IP address while doing `127.0.0.1 acme.com`. It worked for when I tried at my end. It seems like you are hitting some other service

Comment: In my hosts file there are only two rows related to 127.0.0.1: 127.0.0.1 acme.com
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section

Comment: Can you check for the IP address of your Ingress Controller service and point `acme.com` to that IP.

Comment: tried it, didn't help. Postman show requests couldn't be send instead of http 401 when it is 127.0.0.1

Comment: Additional check: Do you get any log in Ingress Controller when you go to  acme.com? If not you may be accessing via wrong port. May be you can try `curl http://acme.com:31860//api/platforms`